# Javascript - is there at good way to create a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field i my webshop that i would like to change to a link

```
<span id="m-product-customdata-data-" class="m-product-customdata-data-title">http://www.coaxconnectors.dk/searchresultcable.asp?CCType=-TL505&amp;action=searchConnector </span>
```

Is there any way i Javascript to change this to a url?

Comment: use anchor tag. You can check this site.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not a code writing forum; You need to show us your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will help you.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "my title text";
a.href = "http://example.com";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```